# Training a neural network, I can't figure out my learning curves

Tags: python, cross-validation, data-visualization, tensorflow, keras

I am cross validating a model, splitted in 5.
Then I plotted for each split, the loss and the val_loss by epochs.

I get something like that:
[image: Training plots, by splits]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/72/7210e5f66a.png))</sub>

**I found this plot disturbing.**

1. Only the first one seems "normal" to me ;
2. I found the loss level very very low
3. I don't get how it's possible to have a val_loss always lower than the training_loss (plot 4 and 5).

**How I cross validate :**

```py
def cv(X, y, model, n_splits=5, epochs=5, batch_size=1024,
       random_state=42, verbose=0):
    # kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=random_state)
    kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=False, random_state=random_state)
    histories = []
    for s in kf.split(X):
        X_train = X.iloc[s[0]].to_numpy()
        y_train = y.iloc[s[0]]['Target'].to_numpy()
        X_test = X.iloc[s[1]].to_numpy()
        y_test = y.iloc[s[1]]['Target'].to_numpy()

        h = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                      verbose=verbose)
        histories.append(h)
    return histories
```

**The model**

```py
def model_8(input_dim) -> tf.keras.models:
    get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})

    inputs = Input(shape=(input_dim,))

    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_1')(inputs)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_2')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_3')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_4')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_5')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_6')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_7')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_8')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_9')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_10')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='swish', name='hl_11')(x)

    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer='adam')
    #model._name = function.__name__
    model._name = inspect.stack()[0][3]
    return model
```

**The plot function:**

```py
def plots_(models_cv_histories, n_splits, save=False):
    """Plot all the learning curves for each trained models


    Arguments:
        models_cv_histories {array} --   array of histoires
    """

    nb_models = len(models_cv_histories)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nb_models,
                             ncols=n_splits, figsize=(12, 5))

    row_index = 0
    for cv_model in models_cv_histories:
        hist = cv_model[1]
        epochs = range(1, len(hist[0].epoch) + 1)

        col_index = 0
        for split_ in hist:
            loss = split_.history['loss']
            epochs = split_.epoch
            val_loss = split_.history['val_loss']
            model_name = split_.model.name

            if nb_models > 1:
                ax = axes[row_index][col_index]
            else:
                ax = axes[col_index]

            ax.set_title(model_name + ' split ' + str(col_index))
            ax.plot(epochs, loss, color="r", label="loss")
            ax.plot(epochs, val_loss, color="g", label="val_loss")
            ax.set_xlabel("epochs")
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
            ax.set_ylabel("loss")
            ax.legend(loc="upper right")

            col_index += 1
        row_index += 1

    fig.subplots_adjust()
    if save:
        plt.savefig("plots/test.png")
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

**Would you give me some hint ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `keras.Model.fit` continues training from where it last stopped, rather than starting training over again from a random initialization. So what's happening is you're training the model on the first CV split, then continuing training on the second CV split, and so on. Instead, you should re-initialize the model before each CV split.

The first clue to what's going on are the ranges of values in the y-axes in your plots. If you're starting from a random initialization, the first loss values should be roughly the same. But in your plots, we can see that the largest values on the y-axis are getting progressively smaller because you're continuing to train the model. (Incidentally, this is why it's important to use consistent axis extents whenever possible, because it makes errors like these very obvious.)

Comment: How thanks !!! It's crystal clear now.